# File into stream -> Stream into info Java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bytebuffer

I've to write a programm which reads an `ecg` recording file and writes the data into variables.

All I've at the moment is the `inputstream` and a `bytebuffer`.

I know from the documentation, that the first 2 `bytes` should represent a `checksum` of [unint16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_%28computer_science%29),The next following 4 `bytes` should give a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in **hex** and so on...

But if I execute the code beneath **it's wont work** because the output for the number is 0.

My question is if I had done something wrong in the **buffer section**. It's strange because If I write the whole stream into an array and then point to the position of the 3 - 6 element the out put will be :

`output += String.format("0x%02X", bC[2]);` and then i **read it upside down** i get the magic number.

```
public class Stream {
private String fileName;
private byte[] storageArray;
private int byteLength;
private byte[] magicNumber;



public Stream(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    try {
        readIt();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void readIt() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ecg-file");

            //for skipping to the desired beginning of the byte stream

    fileIn.skip(0);
    setByteLength(fileIn.available());
    storageArray = new byte[getByteLength()];
    fileIn.read(getStorageArray());
    fileIn.close();
}


public String getCRCNumber () {
    ByteBuffer twoByte = ByteBuffer.wrap(getStorageArray());
    twoByte.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

            //the missing bytes @ the beginning for the int
    twoByte.put((byte)0x00);
    twoByte.put((byte)0x00);
            //shift the start position per 2 bytes 
           // and read the first 2 bytes of the inputstream into the buffer 
    twoByte.position(0x02);
    twoByte.put(getStorageArray(), 0, 2);
    twoByte.flip();
            //creates the int number of the 4 bytes in the buffer
    int result = twoByte.getInt();


    String output = "";
    String b = "\n";


    return output += Integer.toString(result);


}


public int getByteLength() {
    return byteLength;
}

public void setByteLength(int byteLength) {
    this.byteLength = byteLength;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public byte[] getMagicNumber() {
    return magicNumber;
}

public void setMagicNumber(byte[] magicNumber) {
    this.magicNumber = magicNumber;
}

public byte[] getStorageArray() {
    return storageArray;
}

public void setStorageArray(byte[] storageArray) {
    this.storageArray = storageArray;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the use of available(). All it does is tell you how much data is available to be read *without blocking,* which is rarely of much interest, and there is a specific warning in the Javadoc against treating it as the length of the entire input. What you're really interested in is how much data you *need.*

Fortunately there is an easy solution. Wrap the input stream in a `DataInputStream,` and read it as follows:

```
short crc16 = in.readShort();
// check the CRC
String hexString = "0x"+(Integer.toString(in.readInt(), 16));
// ...
```

etc. See the Javadoc.

`skip(0)` does nothing in your code, as that's where you already are when you open the file.

I don't know what you mean by 'read it upside down'.

Comment: Thank's for your answer!
The programm is growing and I'm getting better every day :-D I've rewrote it and now everything is working as expected. The upside down problem was caused by the fact that every type of value in the ecg file is unsigned. So I wrote some functions to make it unsigned.
I hope I can "draw" my first ecg graph in a couple of days :-D. Thanks again for your help. PS: JAVA ROCKS ;)